# Except on list of different type

Tags: c#, list

I have two list `originalSet` of type `List<TypeA>` and `excludibleSet` of type `List<TypeB>`.
I need a new list `newSet` of type `List<TypeA>` that contains only elements of `originalSet` that have nothing to do with elements in `excludibleSet`.

The two type are completely different (only few property in common), so I can't use `Except` with an `EqualityComparer` but I have to all by hand.

In more depth: suppose I have property `prop1` and `prop2` in commons among `TypeA` and `TypeB`.
I want to exclude from `originalSet` all elements that have `prop1` and `prop2` equals to `prop1` and `prop2` of an element in `excludibleSet`.

How can I do this using Linq or in an elegant manner?

Comment: Do TypeA and TypeB derive prop1+2 from the same super type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var newSet = originalSet.Where(x=>!excludibleSet.Any(y=>y.prop1==x.prop1 && 
                                                        y.prop2==x.prop2)
                        ).ToList();
```